Are all complex algebraic varieties in 2+ variables unbounded as a result of Hartogs' extension theorem?
Hartogs' extension theorem states that for any $n\geq 2$, $U\subseteq\mathbb C^n$, $K\subset U$ compact (in $\mathbb C^n$) and a holomorphic function $f:U\setminus K\to\mathbb C$, it can always be analytically extended to $\tilde f:U\to\mathbb C$ such that $f=\tilde f|_{U\setminus K}$. In other words, holomorphic functions in several variables are completely different than those in one variable, since they have no singularities, for instance.
How is this possible? Does this not imply that all algebraic varieties over $\mathbb C[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ are not complact? Since they are closed subsets of $\mathbb C^n$, does this not mean that none are bounded?
For instance, take $f:\mathbb C^2\setminus V\to\mathbb C$, given by $f(z_1,z_2)=\frac{1}{p(z_1,z_2)}$, where $V$ is the variety of the nonconstant (in both variables) polynomial $p(X_1,X_2)\in\mathbb C[X_1,X_2]$. Clearly, $f$ cannot be extended any further as $V$ is its "natural boundary", as defined in Narasimhan's book. Thus, $V$ must be unbounded. Is this correct?

Who is Hertog? Does she really have a theorem named after her? There are other issues with your post as well.

Does this not imply that all algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]$ are not compact? <> Aside from finite sets of points, yes, that's right. Complex-analytically, if $M$ is a compact, connected holomorphic manifold, then every holomorphic function on $M$ is constant. Consequently, every holomorphic map from $M$ to a complex Cartesian space is constant. Particularly, $M$ cannot be holomorphically embedded unless it is a single point.

@MoisheKohan Why does it matter who Hertog is? Why do I have to introduce the person who came up with a theorem? This is completely irrelevant. It's a theorem in complex analysis in several variables. It is mentioned in Narasimhan and Jiri Lebl's books on complex analysis and even has its own Wikipedia page. You can research it if you're interested.

Because you badly misspelled the name, it is Hartogs, not Hertog.

@AndrewD.Hwang What is the difference between a holomorphic manifold and a complex manifold? I am confused. I thought that all smooth 2-manifolds admit a complex structure, and are thus Riemann surfaces, but not holomorphic?

@BorisDimitrov Besides that crediting authorship is a form of respect that can sometimes allow math to be understood in its historical and social context,  I think that it is as important to spell Hartogs correctly than Pythagoras, Poincaré, Gauss or Euler, if not even more important: while one would understand you if you refer to "Pitagoras Theorem", "Poincarre Theorem" or "Gausse Theorem" (maybe not if referring to Pethegor, Poängcare or Gosse) because they are commonly famous names, one would have a hard time trying to understand your question if you spelled Hartogs as Erthog for instance.

@BorisDimitrov Imagine if you misspell Li as Lee, Lih, Leah, or Ly, and that someone looks for them online. Of course, this extreme case is often due to the poor transliterations of non western languages into latine alphabet

@Didier You talking as if I misspelled it intentionally.

@BorisDimitrov I'm not implying that you did it intentionally, I was answering to 'why does it matter who Hertog is?'. My comments are not bad done with bad intention

@Didier The only reason I wrote that is because I didn't realize that the comment I was replying to was about spelling.

@BorisDimitrov Fair enough. Sorry about that then!

Of course holomorphic/meromorphic functions in $n\ge 2$ variables can have singularities. Perhaps you meant isolated singularities?

@TedShifrin Does the word singularity not already imply it being an isolated point?

Absolutely not.

Regarding terminology, where I wrote holomorphic manifold please read complex manifold. I'm merely using terminology that to me is consistent, as well as consistent with terminology for vector bundles. In this usage, a complex structure is an endomorphism field $J$ (defined in some real vector bundle) satisfying $J^2=-I$, while a holomorphic structure further satisfies an integrability condition. The complex projective line is a holomorphic curve (unique structure up to biholomorphism), but "the torus" is not (there exist many non-equivalent holomorphic structures).

@AndrewD.Hwang I didn't understand what J and I are.

Here, $I$ is the identity map of a vector bundle, while $J$ is a vector bundle map (linear in fibers).


Does this not imply that all algebraic varieties over $\mathbb C[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ are not complact? Since they are closed subsets of $\mathbb C^n$, does this not mean that none are bounded?

Yes, this is true (except for the zero-dimensional case) and doesn't require any complex analysis to prove. It follows from Noether normalization that an affine variety of dimension $d$ (maybe I should require irreducibility to be safe) admits a surjective morphism to $\mathbb{A}^d$ and so cannot be compact for $d \ge 1$ (since $\mathbb{A}^d$ is not compact).

What is the "morphism" in this case? Just a continuous map?

@Boris: it's a morphism of complex varieties, so in particular it is continuous in the Euclidean topology.
